# 17.04 Can't uninstall corrupted Libreoffice installed from deb

Tags: uninstall, 17.04, deb

Newbie to 17.04. Tried to install Libreoffice from the deb files downloaded from the Libreoffice website, as per innerwebs instructions when you can't access your Googledrive when Libreoffice is installed from Ubuntu.
Anyway, it was a disaster. Extracted the deb file I thought I wanted for Writer, ended up with an open-ended Libreoffice install with no support, and a random Libremath app.
Tried removing both from the Ubuntu Software utility, it does not uninstall. Won't even get far enough into uninstall to ask for the password.
Tried following directions to uninstall from Terminal, and I get a response that "-g" is not recognized from the -get command.

I'm stumped, and and stupid. Help me out? Name-calling is fine, just get me going in the right direction.

Comment: Here's an update - can't install/uninstall ANY apps.

Comment: Whats the output if you tried to install apps ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh. Please disregard. There was a dependency because I only depackaged one aspect of the entire file.

I misread online directions when they gave commands for "*.deb" files, reading as picking-and-choosing which deb to dpkg. I went back, dpkg 'ed them all with *.deb, and all is well.

As I said, I'm stupid....but learning.... ;-D